# tinymce editor(WIRIS plugin) is not working

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using Tinymce wiris editor to display equation but i am facing problem. after creating equation,on textarea box following error occurs. can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

I am using linux hosting server and i am not doing any changes in configuration.ini files. Still i am getting this error. but above code is working on windows hosting server.

Also i am doing Wiris plugin test and below is status.

[image]

I don't know what is exactly problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your config file content in text format

Comment: Please post the next time the config as text without any unrelated comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue is resolved. Third party communication is not working on my domain(Port 80 get Blocked).After activating port80, it working perfectly.